# Why does function signature for c++ sequential access iterator not use pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

For example in this snippet beg & end, seem to be used as pointers. Yet in the function declaration In *beg, In *end is neither supplied, nor accepted by c++ compiler. Why do we use it like a pointer but not declare it like a pointer argument to function?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

template<class In, class X> void myreplace (In beg, In end, const X& x, const X& y)
{
    while (beg != end)
    {
        if (*beg == x) *beg = y;
        beg++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> veca = { 1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4 };
    myreplace(veca.begin(), veca.end(), 4, 2);
    copy(veca.begin(), veca.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ","));
}
```

Comment: Iterators are abstraction for iterating the underlying containers to which they belong. Since they point to elements in order specific to container, they are used as pointer. Otherwise, they are objects.

Comment: The point of the iterator concept is that you can abstract the concern of how to iterate a collection, and just rely on the standard exposed iterator methods.

Answer (score 1):

[Iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) are usually not just pointers but an abstraction of pointers.

As per their [general requirements](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/iterator.requirements#general-2):

> Their semantics is a generalization of most of the semantics of pointers in C++. This ensures **that every function template that takes iterators works as well with
>   regular pointers**.

So you can also do this instead:

```
myreplace(&veca[0], &veca[6], 4, 2);
```

Where `&veca[0]` and `&veca[6]` are pointers to the first and last elements of the vector `veca` .

This is possible because the  [[] operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) returns a reference to the element at specified location.

Answer (score 0):

The dereference operator can be defined for any use defined type by overloading the unary `operator*` function.

The type returned by `veca.begin()` is such a type. An object of that type can be dereferenced using the `*` operator.

The iterators returned by the `begin()` member functions of most of the containers from the standard library support such an operation. Hence you can use:

```
std::vector<int> a = {10, 20, 30};
std::vector<int>::iterator iter = a.begin();
int item = *iter;
```

and

```
std::set<int> a = {10, 20, 30};
std::set<int>::iterator iter = a.begin();
int item = *iter;
```

and

```
std::map<int, double> a = {{10, 2.5}, {20, 5.8}};
std::map<int, double>::iterator iter = a.begin();
std::pair<int, double> item = *iter;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping you from passing pointers to `myreplace`. e.g. in the call

```
int Carray[7] = { 1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4 };
myreplace(Carray, Carray + 7, 4, 2);
```

The template parameter `In` is deduced to be `int *`, and `X` is deduced to be `int`. It is the same as if you had written

```
void myreplace (int * beg, int * end, const int & x, const int & y)
{
    while (beg != end)
    {
        if (*beg == x) *beg = y;
        beg++;
    }
}
```

It *also* accepts non-pointers that behave sufficiently pointer-like (i.e. model [InputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator))

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean the correct code as below:

```
template<class In, class X> void myreplace (In* beg, In* end, const X& x, const X& y)
{
    while (*beg != *end)
    {
        if (**beg == x) **beg = y;
        *beg++;
    }
}
```

I think firstly you should understand the basic template knowledge in C++, in fact , in STL, iterator is defined as pointer , but it doesn't mean the pointer type is the only one for iterator

```
typedef T* iterator;
```